# How to make the video fit in view in React Native?

Tags: react-native, react-native-camera, react-native-video

I'm using `react-native-video`:

```
<View style={styles.videoView}>
     <Video 
         source={{ uri: strings.sourceUri+"posts/"+this.state.videoSrc }} 
         ref={(ref) => { this.player = ref }}           
         repeat={true}
         resizeMode="contain"                    
         style={styles.videoStyle}
     />
</View>
```

**Styles**

```
videoView: {
  justifyContent:'center', 
  alignItems: 'center', 
  flex: 1,
  flexDirection: 'column',
},
videoStyle: {
  position: 'absolute',
  top: 0,
  left: 0,
  bottom: 0,
  right: 0,
},
```

So I'm fetching a video from api. And I want to show it in my flatlist. But the video is either getting small if I use `resizeMode="contain"` or the size gets bigger if I used  `resizeMode="cover"`. How can I scale my video so that it fits in the view?

I'm using `react-native-camera`. What can I try next?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following setting:
Giving the video a height relative to its parent view might help.

```
videoView: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'column',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
},
videoStyle: {
    alignSelf: 'center',
    height: '80%',
    resizeMode: 'contain'
    },
```

I did the same setting for an image view. I was having trouble scaling the logo so i did this. Hope it helps.

**EDIT:**
since i can't reply to comments yet. Check this detailed article about using videos with react native. It has very detailed info.
https://medium.com/quick-code/react-native-video-component-68262bcbc21f

Comment: It gives me a warning that I can't use `resizeMode` in `videoStyle`.

Comment: add the resizeMode as a prop on video, like you did.